# Retry after Exception in Groovy

Tags: java, ruby, exception, groovy

In Ruby, I can write:

```
begin
  do_something # exception raised
rescue
   # handles error
   retry  # restart from beginning
end
```

Is there something similar in Groovy/Java?

I found [this](http://blog.oio.de/2011/03/23/a-groovy-way-to-retry-method-calls-in-case-of-exceptions/) but maybe there is something better ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could build up your own helper method in Groovy to encapsulate this retry logic.

```
def retry(int times = 5, Closure errorHandler = {e-> log.warn(e.message,e)}
     , Closure body) {
  int retries = 0
  def exceptions = []
  while(retries++ < times) {
    try {
      return body.call()
    } catch(e) {
      exceptions << e
      errorHandler.call(e)
    }        
  }
  throw new MultipleFailureException("Failed after $times retries", exceptions)
}
```

(Assuming a definition of MultipleFailureException similar to [GPars' AsyncException](http://code.google.com/p/gparallelizer/source/browse/trunk/src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/AsyncException.java?r=1074))

then in code, you could use this method as follows.

```
retry {
   errorProneOperation()
}
```

or, with a different number of retries and error handling behaviour:

```
retry(2, {e-> e.printStackTrace()}) {
  errorProneOperation()
}
```

Comment: Now if the `IllegalStateException` would use one of the exceptions (the first? the last? hard to say) as its cause, it would be **much** more useful, as you could see **why** it failed. In production I wouldn't want a stacktrace to be printed each time an attempt failed. I only want to know about it if all retries failed.

Comment: Thanks Joachim - on your suggestion I've added in collecting of individual exceptions. As for not wanting a stacktrace - sure,it's just there to illustrate the point. As exceptions are now being gathered to report at the end, maybe the purpose of the errorHandler is to reset whatever resources are required before `body.call()` is retried - in which case the default closure could just be `{->}`

Comment: Is there then way (for example genereics) to provide exceptions on what retry should be happened (recoverable)? To do not retry on fatals.

Comment: I guess you could use `catch(Exception e) {`
then any java.lang.Error (or subclasses) that aren't recoverable would not be caught, and would bail out straight away.

Comment: How to pass argument to errorProneOperation function? I tried your code, but on 2nd and further attempts parameter passed to function is empty (i'm passing map)?

Answer (score 2):

These days people will advise you to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to implement this kind of try-catch-retry functionality, as `Thread.sleep()` is considered outdated and potentially bad for performance.  I was going to point you to a good answer on this by cletus, but can't for the life of me find it. I'll update my answer if I can dig it up.

**EDIT:** found it: [How to retry function request after a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604763/how-to-retry-function-request-after-a-certain-time) Hopefully this is of some help to you.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to emulate kinda the same (I'm not sure about semantics of `retry`):

```
def retry(handler, c) {
    try {
        c()
    } catch(e) {
        handler(e)
        retry(handler, c)  // restart from beginning
    }
}

def handler = {e ->
    // handles error
}

retry(handler) {
    do_something // exception raised
}
```